# how to get common objects from array in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def array1=[{id:1,name:"abc"},{id:2,name:"pqr"},{id:3,name:"xyz"}]

def array2=[{id:1,name:"abc"},{id:4,name:"efg"}]
```

The result Should be

```
[{id:1,name:"abc"}]
```

If id from array1 matches id of array2 then it gives that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess arrays intersection will be helpful in your case:

```
array1.intersect(array2)
```

It returns common member from two arrays.
But if you're looking for only id comparison:

```
 array1.findAll { elem ->
     array2.count { it.id == elem.id } > 0
 }
```

Comment: how to print the value of result

Comment: def someValue = {one of expression from my answer}. Then println(someValue)